# getting Yii Filters for CArrayDataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I'm fetching the data from two tables and sending that array to CArrayDataProvider, and which is in other controller, I want (filter or search) option for one of my column. can any one help me, how to achieve that.

I will be thank full for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this wiki:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/

Also make sure to read comments and related forum topic linked in article.